# Name a dataframe using an iteratively produced string in Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm somewhat new to Python/Pandas and I keep running into this particular use case that I cannot find a way around.  I would like to create a series of DataFrames with names that are iteratively produced.  Here's an example of what I'd like to work in theory

```
list1_A = DataFrame([(1,3,2),(2,4,5)])
list2_A = DataFrame([(1,5,2),(5,2,3)])
list3_A = DataFrame([(5,2,1),(3,3,6)])

listOfDFs = [list1_A, list2_A, list3_A]
for i in range(len(listofDFs)):
     'list'+str(i)+'A' = 'list'+str(i)+'A' + 5
```

I have tried multiple ways to get around this but it's a use case that keeps coming up for me.  In R, I've used assign('dfName',value).

Comment: Why do you want to do this instead of just using your list?  You don't really gain anything by typing `list1_A` instead of `listOfDFs[0]`.

Comment: In numpy I'd make a three-dimensional array. I think the panda-ish (ailuropodic?) way is to make a hierarchically indexed DataFrame, in which your iteratively produced names are column labels in the outer hierarchy.

Comment: Also this line seems just weird, as well as a syntax error: `'list'+str(i)+'A' = 'list'+str(i)+'A' + 5 `. What do you want to produce?  Perhaps you want to iterate over the DFs: `for i in listofDFs: i += 5` alters each DF in place.

Comment: in which case, `newDFlist = [x + 5 for x in listOfDFs]`. Also, case typo in listOfDFs vs listofDFs.

Comment: Thanks BrenBarn- your solution works.  I knew I was missing something simple.  Cphlewis- I was just a toy example of something I wanted to conceptually achieve, sorry for the typos.

Comment: On testing this- BrenBarn's solution doesn't work. Here's the actual code I'm using (instead of the toy example) and the error (I tried replacing the names of the Df's with the actual names and the code runs fine). oldDFList[i][oldDFList[i]['exp_name'].isnull()==False]

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of pandas, starting with the end of your code:

```
import pandas as pd
allDFs = pd.concat(listOfDFs)
mI = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['list'+i+'A' for i in list('112233')],[0,1]*3],names=['A','B'])
allDFs.index=mI
```

resulting multi-indexed DataFrame:

> ```
>           0  1  2
> A      B         
> list1A 0  1  3  2
>        1  2  4  5
> list2A 0  1  5  2
>        1  5  2  3
> list3A 0  5  2  1
>        1  3  3  6
> ```

and there's so much pandas can do with a MultiIndexed dataframe: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/advanced.html#advanced. E.g., slicing or selecting on any of the criteria and running tests or operations:

```
allDFs.xs(0,level='B')[0]==1
```

> ```
> A
> list1A     True
> list2A     True
> list3A    False
> ```